# In Django, how to get all instances of a model where an instance of another model related to the first by fk does not exist?

Tags: python, django

This is really tricky to me. I have the following models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
      item_type = models.CharField(choices=item_choices)

class Suggestion(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(User)
      item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
```

I need to get all the items of a given item_type that don't have a suggestion related to it and to a given user. Can this be achieved in one query?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with `.exclude()`:

```
items = Item.objects.filter(item_type=item_type).exclude(suggestion__user=user)
```

This follows the backwards relation to `Suggestion`, and the forward relation to `User`, and excludes any `Item`s where the related user matches the given user.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to create a queryset of items with suggestions related to the user, then use that as a subquery.

```
items_suggested_by_user = Item.objects.filter(suggestion__user=user)
item_types = Item.objects.filter(item_type=item_type)
items = item_types.exclude(item__in=items_suggested_by_user)
```